# Security Concerns for using Google Javascript APIs through Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I can't find any answer to my question so here you go !

I have recently developed a Google Chrome extension that uses the provided Google Javascript API in order to have access to some content of a specific tab/page.

As the content of the page is confidential, are there any risks that Google stores it somewhere ? I'm not too familiar with Security of APIs and thought that you might be able to help

Thank you,
Kind Regards,

Yohann

Comment: I believe this question was asked and answered hundreds of times during past ~10 years like "Does/can Google spy on us or expose our sensitive data?" It's a legal question, not really programming-related. Anyway you should not store these values, use onetime tokens that expire after some time.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer ! When you mean "value stored", it's related to the variable(s) I'm using in the content script ? In this case, the only variable I'm storing is a non-confidential one. So I guess there's no real answer to this :D

Comment: `Stored` means in the `chrome.storage.sync` which is the only storage that is automatically transferred to Google's servers (in encrypted form that makes the real data inaccessible for the Google company as far as I know, at least this is what all the online companies do or claim to do).